# Back to App from SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I have created a frame work having 3 view controller inside it

User APP view name

```
userViewController
      |
      clickherebtn      to load Framework
```

framework appviews:

```
sdkview1controller
sdkview2controller
sdkview3controller
```

Call from App to framework flow

on hit clickherebtn i load framework like this [tutorial way](http://insert.io/frameworkios8xcode6/)

from going back from sdkview1controller view simply used

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

but how if my calling view are like

userViewController -> sdkview1controller-> sdkview2controller-> sdkview3controller

Now i want to jump back to userViewController on hitting back button in sdkview3controller

NOTE: userViewController is name is not fixed, so my question is
how to get back to app view , skipping all loaded views in my framework directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIViewController *vc = self.presentingViewController;
NSArray* classes = @[[sdkview1controller class],
[sdkview2controller class],
[sdkview3controller class]];

while (vc.presentingViewController) {
     vc = vc.presentingViewController;

   if(! [classes containsObject:[vc class]])
         break;
}
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

if you added all your view controllers with `presentViewController:` (which is I assume you did) this will dismiss all the chain and get the user back to `userViewController`

Comment: but it dismiss all the views even from the app which are presentVieController based

Comment: try my updated code. it should give an idea at least

Comment: accepted as i have knows view so i execute loop for number of times to get back to app view

Answer (score 1):

**In your app** 
add a navigation controller as rootviewcontroller and push framework viewcontroller as:

```
 Common *com_obj = [Common sharedInstance];
  com_obj.viewc =self; ////////assiging the app viewcontroller which will be used to pop
 NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CommonBundle" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *mobtestBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];

UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:mobtestBundle];
ViewController1 *viewc1=[story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewc1 animated:YES];
```

**In your sdk**

In your object class add a property as id viewc

```
/////in sdkViewcontroller1 push as 

ViewController2 *viewc1=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewc1 animated:YES];
```

In back sdkViewcontroller2

```
Common *common = [Common sharedInstance];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:common.viewc animated:YES];
```

Comment: don't get you! please what is Common ?

Comment: Common is the Library NSobject Class file.